# Emoji anime pop-quiz

Tags: emoji, anime

Found a quiz in an old dialogue of mine. First to guess all five gets the tick.

[image]

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way but I think these last couple puzzles are not acessible to a wide audience and are unecessarily very niche in its category of knowledge. I would advise that you make puzzles themed in a way that is more accessible to the general audience as to spark more interest in them. If you are going to make an anime themed puzzle try to make it based on more commonly known ones.

Comment: @PrinceDeepthinker I've seen puzzles on this site that remain unguessed for ages, so niche they are :D If you have a certain type of puzzles that you're into, I can make some of those so you have something to do. You can't comfort everyone, unless you make something very easy to solve.

Comment: I am not asking for easy puzzles just ones whose field of knowledge is more widely known throughout the the anglophone world at least as an entry point. Some puzzles do culminate in rather odd facts and that is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are my guesses:

> 1. Shingeki no Kyojin (Attack on Titan)
>  Explanation: 
>  - The black and yellow striped barrier emojis represent the walls. 
>  - The crying character in the middle represents Eren Yeager, crying over the death of his mother by a Titan. This results in Eren intensely hating the Titans. 
>  - The stone-faced men at the end represent the Titans.

> 2. Code Geass 
>  Explanation: 
>  - The flags of Great Britain represent the Holy Britannian Empire, which invades Japan (as seen by the flag at the end). 
>  - The fist, spiral, and eyes emojis seem to represent Lelouch Vi Britannia. The fist represents Lelouch fighting against the Britannian Empire. The spiral and eyes are a reference to his power, allowing him to control and manipulate others. 
>  - The character next to the Flag of Japan is Kururugi Suzaku, the other protagonist of the series.

> 3. Death Note 
>  Explanation: 
>  - The apples and skull emoji represent Ryuk, a Death God who loves apples. 
>  - The book represents the Death Note. 
>  - The two characters next to the fist and scissors are Light Yagami and L, the two main characters who engage in a battle of wits over the course of the anime. 
>  - The chocolate, cookie, and ice-cream is a reference to the fact that L loves sweet stuff.

> 4. One Piece 
>  Explanation: 
>  - Bags of Gold next to a Cat emoji seem to refer to Nami, who loves gold and is referred to as a "Cat Burglar" in the series 
>  - Water droplets and ships emojis represent rain and ships, which are common in the world of One Piece. 
>  - The fist, muscle, and 2 yellow rocket-like emoji next to the smiling character seem to represent Luffy, who has the ability to elongate his arm due to the Rubber-Rubber Fruit. The smiling character also fits Luffy because of his happy-go-lucky nature. 
>  - The fruits seem to be a reference to the Devil Fruits, capable of granting super-human powers to whoever consumes them. 
>  - The other faces seem to be a reference to the Straw Hat Pirates. The skull especially seems to be a reference to Brook, who is a skeleton.

> 5. Soul Eater 
>  Explanation: 
>  - The 99 pink hearts (as corrected by OP) represent the 99 corrupted souls that the main character, Maka Albarn has already collected in the first episode. The purple heart represents the soul of a witch, which is needed by Maka to turn her weapon into a Death Scythe.

Comment: It's pretty precise with 1-4, though you dug even deeper somewhere (cat in the 4 was just meant to be a sideways face to represent someone talking about their treasure as the first thing that happens). You probably won't guess the last one, but the important thing about this items (which represent not exactly hearts) are their color and quantity.

Comment: I just realised that I messed it up and there were supposed to be 99, not 100 pink hearts. I'll give you the tick in a while, I suppose. But try to guess anyway.

Comment: @ThomasBlue Updated answer. (Although I have never seen this show, so I don't know how accurate this is)

Comment: Everything is correct, you get the tick!